# How to disable headings in simple MDE editor

Tags: javascript, markdown, slack, codemirror, simplemde

I have problem about headings when make a custom slack editor based on simple MDE (codemirror). I don't want display heading option while writing.

I only want display normal text like `# cacsac`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "normal text"? You are showing inline code in your question. Do you mean "`# cacsac`"? "# cacsac"? What about other heading levels `##` to `######`?

Comment: @Chris i want to disable heading levels